# AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'most_similar' (Word2Vec)

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I am using Word2Vec and using a wiki trained model that gives out the most similar words. I ran this before and it worked but now it gives me this error even after rerunning the whole program. I tried to take off  `return_path=True` but im still getting the same error

```
print(api.load('glove-wiki-gigaword-50', return_path=True))
model.most_similar("glass")
```

#ERROR:

```
/Users/me/gensim-data/glove-wiki-gigaword-50/glove-wiki-gigaword-50.gz
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-153-3bf32168d154> in <module>
      1 print(api.load('glove-wiki-gigaword-50', return_path=True))
----> 2 model.most_similar("glass") 

AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'most_similar'
```

#MODEL
this is the model I used

```
    print(
        '%s (%d records): %s' % (
            model_name,
            model_data.get('num_records', -1),
            model_data['description'][:40] + '...',
        )
    )
```

Edit: here is my gensim download & output

```
!python -m pip install -U gensim
```

OUTPUT:

Requirement already satisfied: gensim in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (4.0.1)

Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.3 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from gensim) (1.20.1)

Requirement already satisfied: smart-open>=1.8.1 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from gensim) (5.1.0)

Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.18.1 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from gensim) (1.6.2)

Comment: Don't you mean just ```model.similar```?

Comment: @ewong it gives me this: ```AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'similar'```

Comment: Are there more lines to your code, or is that all?  Where is model defined?

Comment: @ewong there is this 
```for model_name, model_data in sorted(info['models'].items()):
    print(
        '%s (%d records): %s' % (
            model_name,
            model_data.get('num_records', -1),
            model_data['description'][:40] + '...',
        )
    )```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are probably looking for `<MODEL>.wv.most_similar`, so please try:

```
model.wv.most_similar("glass")
```

Comment: hi! I tried this but it gives me ```AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'vw'```.     i updated my post with the model I used

Comment: Right. Interesting. Can you please post the version of the `gensim` library you are using too (as there were changes on the way)?

Comment: I used ```import gensim.models.word2vec as w2v``` and ```import gensim.downloader as api```

Comment: This is not what I asked for. Can you please run `pip show gensim` and post the output?

Comment: Hello, I just added them to my post at the end @sophros

Comment: I just spotted it - it was a typo - `wv` instead of `vw`. Please check again!

Comment: Happy to hear! I would appreciate accepting the answer (gray tick mark on the left) and upvoting it.

Comment: actually, i realized that answer pointed to another model, not the wiki one. However, when I took off ```return_path=True``` it worked! thank you so much through

Answer (score 0):

Your shown code...

```
print(api.load('glove-wiki-gigaword-50', return_path=True))
model.most_similar("glass")
```

...doesn't assign anything into `model`. (Was it assigned earlier?)

And, using `return_path=True` there means the `api.load()` will only return a string path to the datafile. That'd only be interesting if you were going to use that string to then do your own loading of the data into a model.

That `api.load()` call without `return_path=True` likely returns an instance of `KeyedVectors`, which is a set of vectors. That's different from a full `Word2Vec` model, but would still support a `.most_similar()` method. However, if you're just `print()`ing that returned path, or returned model, it's not going to be in the `model` variable for your later `.most_similar()` operation.

So you may want:

```
kv_model = api.load('glove-wiki-gigaword-50')
similars = kv_model.most_similar('glass')
print(similars)
```

(Personally, I don't like the opaque magic, & running of new downloaded code, that `api.load()` does. I think it's a better habit to *download the raw data files yourself*, from a known source, so that you know what files have arrived, to which directories, on your own machine. Then *use a dataset-specific load method to load that data*, so that you learn what library methods work with which kinds of files.)

If your `model` variable does in fact include a full `Word2Vec` model, from some unshown other code, then it will also *contain* a set of vectors in its `.wv` (for **w**ord-**v**ectors) property:

```
similars = model.wv.most_similar('glass')
print(similars)
```

Comment: This prints out similar words based on the training of my data. However, I would like to get the words that are trained by ```'glove-wiki-gigaword-50'```

Comment: Have you tried assigning the results of your `api.load()` call into a variable instead of printing it? (You could assign it into `model` if you want to discard the `Word2Vec` model that's already there. Or you could assign it into a new variable like `kv_model`, to reflect that it's just a `KeyedVectors`.)

Comment: I tried it and it gave me ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'most_similar'
```

Comment: What code did you try that gave that error? (That sounds like you assigned a string into the variable, not the results of `api.load()`.)

Comment: This is what I did: ```kv_model= (api.load('glove-wiki-gigaword-50', return_path=True))
(kv_model.most_similar("glass"))```

Comment: Aha, try it without the `return_path=True` argument. If you include that, it means you're asking for the string path to the dataset file, rather than the loaded model itself. I'll also add a note about this to my main answer.